# How to implement hashtags in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, tags, linkify

How can I implement hashtags in an app in one activity? I have looked at an example of using hashtags with linkify but it uses separate activities(http://sourabhsoni.com/implementing-hashtags-in-android-application/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subclass [`ClickableSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) and define whatever special click logic should occur in `onClick`. You can use the same regular expression pattern used in the article and find the parts of the text that match using a [`Matcher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) object. Create a [`SpannableString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) with the existing text and add spans to it wherever the Matcher finds any matches in the text.